# wordpress thumbnail onclick then modal will come out

Tags: theme-development, twitter-bootstrap, media-modal

I have a thumbnail in wordpress, now when the thumbnail image is click, i want a modal to appear. Something just a bootstrap modal. How Can i do this? . any tutoria with this?. there are only few articles related with this. I dont want to use any plugin. I want to make a dynamic modal when my thumbnail was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to just grab an existing modal library and enqueue that to your theme.  Bootstrap would work (although it would be excessive if you only need a modal window), just enqueue your bootstraps CSS and JavaScript files in your functions.php in your child theme and then you can create the appropriate classes for your modal window.  Here are the WordPress codex references on enqueuing:

[Enqueue Script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

[Enqueue Style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)

Comment: can you give me example how to do it ? . I have a for example a thumbnail then linked to a modal. How can i make the modal dynamic ?. Is it thru post ? How ?